# Undefined index in php when trying to output the subcategories of each category from a phpmyadmin table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, undefined-index

I have 2 tables in phpmyadmin.I output the category names from this table like this in php:

```
<?php
$query="select * from category " ; 
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$query); 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
  echo '<li>
      <a href="subcat.php?cat='.$row[ 'cat_id']. '&catnm='.$row[ "cat_nm"]. '">'.$row[ "cat_nm"]. '
      </a>
      </li>'; 
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Then if the user clicks at one of these categories a list of subcategories which belong to the category clicked by the user will be outputed from my subcat table. The foreign key for subcat table is cat_id. 
An error occures when I try to output the subcategories like this:

```
<?php
$q = "select * from subcat  where parent_id = ".$_GET['cat'];//line 6
$cat=$_GET['cat_nm'];//line 8
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$q) or die("Can't Execute Query..");
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
do
  {
    echo '<li>'.$row1['subcat_nm'].'</li>';
   }
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
?>
```

The error outputed is:
[image]
The cat and cat_nm are columns name of category table.Have I done something wrong here?
Which is the right way to output the subcategories? Thanks!

Comment: Validation would help your cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because,

```
$_GET['cat_nm'] != $_GET['catnm']
```

Look at your link,

```
<a href="subcat.php?cat='.$row[ 'cat_id']. '&catnm='.$row[ "cat_nm"]. '">'.$row[ "cat_nm"]. '

--------------------------------------------^^^^^^
```

It should be `$_GET['catnm']`.

**ProTip**

You *should* be validating your user input and using [prepared statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to prevent [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: Now it says :Undefined index: catnm in C:\xampp\htdocs\diloma\Book_store\subcat.php on line 8